# AJAX loading on the second button click only

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to load AJAX data from the TwitchAPI. I want to keep the data stored in a global variable so I can keep manipulating after the first request, as opposed to calling the API again each time, which is why I am pushing the object's properties to an array. For some reason, when I click the button that triggers the AJAX call, nothing happens. Then, if I press it a second time, the data loads and creates a DIV with all the necessary data filled in. Why doesn't the data load on the first click? Thanks!

```
var test = [];

var streams; 
$("#test").click(function(){
  getData();
  for (i=0; i <test.length; i++){
    title = test[i][0];
    source = test[i][1];
    generateContainers(title, source);
  }
})

function generateContainers(title, source){
    jQuery('<div/>', {
    id: 'foo',
    class: 'test widthSetter',
    href: 'http://google.com',
    title: 'Become a Googler',
    rel: 'external',
    html: "'<img src='"+source+"'</img>"+' ' +title,
}).appendTo('#contentHolder');
}

function getData(){
  URL = "https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/featured";
  $.getJSON(URL, function(channel) {
    len = channel.featured.length;
    for (i=0; i <len; i++){
     title = (channel["featured"][i]["title"]);
     source = (channel["featured"][i]["image"]);
     test.push([title,source]);
     //generateContainers(title, source);
    }
  }
);

}
```

Comment: I'm assuming your issue is with the asynchronous nature of AJAX. The for loop is probably being run before your ajax call completes, and is looping therefore over an empty array. The second time you hit the button the array is populated from the previous call, so it actually created the elements.

Comment: That makes sense..but how do I fix it?

Comment: Remove the for loop from your click function and uncomment the generateContainers line should do it